# jQuery - Adding same actions for multiple events & Binding

Tags: jquery, binding

I've been trying to find a way to add the same action for multiple events.

I have the following action assigned to #comid (which is a select menu).

```
$("#comid").change(function()
{
    comid = $("#comid").val();
    //alert(comid);

    $('#com_photo').addClass('loading');

    $('#com_photo').load('ajax.php?requestType=ajax&action=get_com_photo&comid=' + comid, function() {
        $('#com_photo').removeClass('loading');
        $('#com_photo img').hide();
        $('#com_photo img').fadeIn(1000);
        alert('Image Loaded.');
    });
});
```

Now, the above code works well. When the user selects an item from the select menu the change event is triggered and the ajax request is made and the image is showed along with a alert window saying "Image Loaded".

But, i want the same action to trigger if the user doesn't use the mouse and instead is using keyboard keyup/keydown to select from the menu. It doesn't do that by default which i hoped it did but that doesnt seem to be the case so i want to assign the same action for the keyup or keydown event but i dont want to write (or copy/paste) the same code over again.

After a while of searching i found out about the bind(), i tried do it like this:

```
$("#comid").bind('keyup',function(event){
    $("#comid").trigger('change');
}
```

It works, but when i use the keyup, i see the alert window twice saying "Image Loaded", so i find that behavior unwanted since it seems like it is making the request twice.

Is there something i am doing wrong? or are there any better alternatives to what i'm trying to accomplish?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: The change event should still fire when changed with the keyboard.  the difference I think is that it won't fire until onblur, or the user clicks somewhere else after changing it using the keyboard.

Comment: Right, that's the issue. is there any workaround for that?

Answer (score 8):

```
$("#comid").bind('change keyup', function(){
    ...
});
```

You can attach your function to multiple events like this. Check the documentation for [bind](http://api.jquery.com/bind/), it's pretty useful.

You may also want to read about [live](http://api.jquery.com/live/). It does (pretty much) the same thing as bind, but the function will be applied to any newly created (matching) elements as well.

*Edit: for your select menu, the function will fire twice if you use the arrow keys to select an option. In your case, you should just use change(). Keyup() is not needed.*

Comment: +1, for simpler and nicer syntax -> easier solution (depending on situation).

Comment: Yes, i already got introduced to binding alittle. and i've also tried that method by putting the events together but it still does the same thing.
`$("body").bind('change keyup', function(){
alert('text message');
});`

Comment: In my above comment, that's just an example code to show the behavior i'm speaking about.

Comment: Oh I see what you're asking now. You should just use the change() function. There's no reason to use keyup() for a select menu. Hope that helps! :)

Comment: Yes, i was doing that at first but when using only Change() event, the select menu doesn't run the Change Event until it looses focus, and that's why i have been trying to use the KeyUp or KeyDown event. But when i use KeyUp or KeyDown it makes the request twice. is there any workaround for that Select Menu behavior? that it doesn't trigger the change() Event until it looses focus, because i want it to trigger the change event as soon as the item from the menu changes, it does that perfectly for the mouse click but not the keyboard key up and down.

Comment: I don't see why you need it to do that. If a user is trying to make a selection, they make their selection and then confirm it by clicking off or pressing enter. That is the point at which you should use the data. My answer still works with the up and down arrow keys.

Comment: Not everyone thinks that way, not all user are expected to understand that they have click somewhere else or even press Enter to see the change. The answer you posted does work but i also posted something similar in my original post `$("#comid").bind('keyup',function(event){
    $("#comid").trigger('change');
}` your version is shorter, but in the end i'm seeing the same results that the alert box is opening twice when using the keyboard up and down, its making double request which i dont want it to do.

Comment: I guess, if i can't find a solution / workaround for either of the issues **(Binding change and key up/down  making Multiple Request or change event not triggering until loosing focus)** - I'll just stick with only using the Change Event, and ignore the key up/down until i come across a solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can bind multiple events with live():

```
$("#comid").live({
  click: function(){/* code */},
  change: function(){/* code */}
});
```

You can then just wrap your script into a function and call that function at all events.

More info at [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/live/).